# Split string without losing split character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string in Java some string like this, normal split function splits the string while losing the split characters:

```
String = "123{456]789[012*";
```

I want to split the string for `{,[,],*` character but don't want to lose them. I mean I want results like this:

```
part 1 = 123{
part 2 = 456]
part 3 = 789[
part 4 = 012*
```

Normally split function splits like this:

```
part 1 = 123
part 2 = 456
part 3 = 789
part 4 = 012
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zero-width lookahead/behind expressions to define a regular expression that matches the zero-length string *between* one of your target characters and anything that is not one of your target characters:

```
(?<=[{\[\]*])(?=[^{\[\]*])
```

Pass this expression to `String.split`:

```
String[] parts = "123{456]789[012*".split("(?<=[{\\[\\]*])(?=[^{\\[\\]*])");
```

If you have a block of consecutive delimiter characters this will split once at the end of the whole block, i.e. the string `"123{456][789[012*"` would split into four blocks `"123{", "456][", "789[", "012*"`.  If you used just the first part (the look-behind)

```
(?<=[{\[\]*])
```

then you would get *five* parts `"123{", "456]", "[", "789[", "012*"`

Comment: can you show me with a little code because i dint understand well, how to look ahead/behind

Comment: @RecreatioN does that help?  A zero-width lookahead `(?=X)` matches the point immediately before any match of the expression `X`, a look-behind matches the point immediately after.

Comment: Thank you verry much this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Using a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<={|\[|\]|\*)
```

---

```
String str = "123{456]789[012*";
String parts[] = str.split("(?<=\\{|\\[|\\]|\\*)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[123{, 456], 789[, 012*]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like

```
String str = "123{456]789[012*";
String[] parts = new String[] {
        str.substring(0,4), str.substring(4,8), str.substring(8,12),
        str.substring(12)
};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output is

```
[123{, 456], 789[, 012*]
```

Comment: but that string is a example so i need a general approximation to split long strings

Comment: @RecreatioN You'll have to be more specific. This is a general algorithm to split a `String` of length 16 into 4 4 character `String`s. If you need something else, you need to explain what that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PatternMatcher` to find the next index after a splitting character and the splitting character itself.

```
public static List<String> split(String string, String splitRegex) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(splitRegex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    int index = 0;
    while (index < string.length()) {
        if (m.find()) {
            int splitIndex = m.end();
            String splitString = m.group();
            result.add(string.substring(index,splitIndex-1) + splitString);
            index = splitIndex;
        } else
            result.add(string.substring(index));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(split("123{456]789[012*","\\{|\\]|\\[|\\*"));
}
```

Output:

```
[123{, 456], 789[, 012*]
```